# reading huge data from database and writing into xml Java

Tags: java, xml, database

I have huge data billions of records in tables what is the best way to read it in plain Java and write it in XML file?

Thanks

Comment: In terms of the time it'll take?

Comment: Read w/ standard selects piece by piece and dump into a file, it's a straightforward procedure. Composing xml by hand is plain simple.

Comment: @ user521180: it needs to happen very quickly few seconds

Comment: I must say I don't think you could do it in a few seconds (though it does depend on the server). On my server, 125 MX XML file with around 250 000 entries, every entry has 30 elements, takes 1 minute. If that's good enough, i'll post you what I do. If it's not, i'll be happy to use a better solution someone else provides.

Answer (score 1):

If by best you mean fastest - I would consider using native database tools to dump the files as this will be way faster than using JDBC.

Comment: need to do it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Java (+Hibernate?) will slow the process down unnecessarily. Easier to do sqlplus script and spool formatted fields into your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be using database inbuild procedure (e.g. XML path) to get data already converted in xml format.

Now there are 2 ways to write in the file:
1. If you have to have Java interface (JDBC) to retrieve data (due to business req) then I'll simply read this data and write in a File (No XML Parser involvement unless you need to verify the output).
2. If you do not have Java restriction then I'll simply write a Stored Procedure which will dump XML data in a file.

**Update to comment:**

**Workflow for fastest retrieval:**

1. Create Stored Procedure which will retrieve data and dump into a file.
2. Call this SP through Java (as you said you need it)
3. Either SP can return you the file name or you can create SP which will take file name so you can dynamically manage the output location.

I have not used Oracle for a very long time but I hope this [link](http://www.oracle.com/oramag/oracle/01-jul/o41xml.html) can help you to kickstart.

Comment: Wats your database? Also, do you have to have Java interface?

Comment: Oracle database Java interface will be gr8 but wud not mind knowing another ways as well.

Answer (score 0):

On Toad you can right click a table and click export to xml. on the commercial version I think you can export all tables but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

If the DB is Oracle, then you can simply use JDBC with a SQLX query.  This will generate your result set directly as XML fragments on the server much faster than if you'd do it on your own on the client side.  SQLX has been available since 8.1.7 as project Aurora and since 9i in standard as XMLDB.

Here is a simple example.

```
select XMLelement ("Process", 
                   XMLelement( "number", p.p_ka_id, '.', p_id ), 
                   XMLElement( "name", p.p_name ), 
                   XMLElement ( "processGroup", pg.pg_name ) ) 
from
    PMP_processes p, 
    PMP_process_groups pg
where 
    condition ;
```

In addition to XMLelement, SQLX has XMLattribute, XMLforest, XMLaggregate... which allows you any resulting tree.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility (working with all db with a JDBC driver) would be to use Apache Cocoon.  There are actually two ways: XSP ((alone or and with ESQL).  Both technos are really quick to develop.

XSP alone example.  Think of XSP as a little bit like JSP but generating XML instead of HTML.  From a DB for instance.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsp:page language="java" xmlns:xsp="http://apache.org/xsp"
  xmlns:esql="http://apache.org/cocoon/SQL/v2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://apache.org/cocoon/SQL/v2 xsd/esql.xsd"
  space="strip">

  <xsp:structure>
     <xsp:include>java.sql.Connection</xsp:include>
     <xsp:include>java.sql.DriverManager</xsp:include>
     <xsp:include>java.sql.PreparedStatement</xsp:include>
     <xsp:include>java.sql.SQLException</xsp:include>
     <xsp:include>java.sql.ResultSet</xsp:include>
  </xsp:structure>

  <xsp:logic><![CDATA[

    private static final String connectionString =
           "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mandarin?user=mandarin&password=mandarin" ;

     private Connection conn = null ;
     private PreparedStatement pstmt = null ;

     private void openDatabase() {
    try {
       DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection (connectionString);
       pstmt = conn.prepareStatement( 
                "select "                     +
                " count(*) as cardinality "   +
                " from "                      +
                "   unihan50    u "           +
                " where "                      +
                "    unicode_id >= ? and "    +
                "    unicode_id <= ? " ) ;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

     private int getRangeCardinality ( int lowerBound, int upperBound ) {
        int cnt = 0 ;
        try {
           cnt = 2 ;
           pstmt.setInt ( 1, lowerBound ) ;
           pstmt.setInt ( 2, upperBound ) ;
           boolean sts = pstmt.execute () ;
           if ( sts ) {
              ResultSet rs = pstmt.getResultSet();
          if (rs != null && rs.next() ) {
                 cnt = rs.getInt ( "cardinality" ) ;
          }
            }
         } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return cnt ;
        }

        private void closeDatabase() {
            try {
                pstmt.close () ;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                conn.close () ;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
    ]]>
     </xsp:logic>

     <ranges>
         <xsp:logic><![CDATA[
              openDatabase() ;

             for  ( int i = 0; i < 16 ; i++ ) {
                  int from = i * 0x1000 ;
                  int to   = i * 0x1000 + 0x0fff ;
             ]]>
             <range>
                <from>0x<xsp:expr>Integer.toString(from, 16)</xsp:expr></from>
                <to>0x<xsp:expr>Integer.toString(to, 16)</xsp:expr></to>
                <count><xsp:expr>getRangeCardinality ( from, to )</xsp:expr></count>
             </range>
             }
             closeDatabase () ;
            </xsp:logic>
        </ranges>
    </xsp:page>
```

XSP is even more straightforward coupled with ESQL.  Here is sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsp:page language="java" xmlns:xsp="http://apache.org/xsp"
  xmlns:esql="http://apache.org/cocoon/SQL/v2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsp-request="http://apache.org/xsp/request/2.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://apache.org/cocoon/SQL/v2 xsd/esql.xsd"
  space="strip">

  <keys>
    <esql:connection>
    <esql:pool>mandarinMySQL</esql:pool>
    <esql:execute-query>
      <esql:query><![CDATA[
         select
            unicode_id,
            kMandarin,
            ...
         from
            unihan50_unified
         where
            add_strokes = 0
         order by
             radical
         ]]>
      </esql:query>
      <esql:results>
         <esql:row-results><key><esql:get-columns /></key></esql:row-results>
      </esql:results>
      </esql:execute-query>
   </esql:connection>
</keys>
</xsp:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use StAX to write the xml, not DOM.

Answer (score -1):

You can query to the database and retrieve all data into a RESULTSET and use the following code to start off a root element.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document  = documentBuilder.newDocument();

Element Element_root  = document.createElement("rootElement");
```

Thereafter you can add on as many as child elements using

```
Element Element_childnode      = document.createElement("childnode");//create child node                
Element_childnode.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Enter the value of text here"));//add data to child node
Element_root.appendChild(Element_childnode);//close the child node
```

**Do not forget to close the opened node close the root at the end WITHOUT FAIL**

Use this to close root.

```
document.appendChild(Element_causelist);
```

At the end if you have a XSD validate it your xml against it.....googling the validation online will provide good results....  http://tools.decisionsoft.com/schemaValidate/

NOTE : **TIME !!! It will take time when data is huge nos...
But I think this is one and the most easiest way of doing it....Taking in consideration the data, I think one should run the program during down time when there is less traffic....**

Hope this helps....Good Luck Gauls....

Comment: Please can you explain the -ve vote....who so ever did it......can you explain whats wrong in the answer

Comment: I didn't downvote but creating a tree-based structure in memory from "billions" of records is going to be extremely memory intensive.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class someclassname{

public static String somemethodname(){        

    String sql;
    sql="SELECT * from yourdatabase.yourtable ";
   return sql; 
}
public static String anothermethodname(){        
    /*this is another method which is used to excute another query simultaneously*/
    String sql;
    sql="SELECT * from youdatabase.yourtable2";
   return sql; 
}

private static void saveasxml(String sql,String targetFile) throws SQLException, XMLStreamException, IOException{    
    int i,count;
    FileOutputStream fos;

    try{

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://yourdomain:yourport/yourdatabase","username","password");
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();

    count=rsmd.getColumnCount();
    XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
    fos=new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
    XMLStreamWriter writer = outputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(fos);
        writer.writeStartDocument();
        writer.writeCharacters("\n");
        writer.writeStartElement("maintag line");
        writer.writeCharacters("\n");

    while(rs.next()){
            writer.writeCharacters("\t");
            writer.writeStartElement("foreveyrow-tagline");
            writer.writeCharacters("\n\t");
        for(i=1;i<count+1;i++){

            writer.writeCharacters("\t");
            writer.writeStartElement("Field"+i);
            writer.writeCharacters(rs.getString(i));
            writer.writeEndElement();
            writer.writeCharacters("\n\t");     
        }
            writer.writeEndElement();
            writer.writeCharacters("\n");   
    } 
        writer.writeEndElement();
        writer.writeEndDocument();
        writer.close();
}catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){    
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    saveasxml(somemethodname(), " file location-path");
    saveasxml(anothermethodname(), "file location path");
}
```

}

Comment: What is the solution that your code is describing? Please include some explanation. Thanks!

Comment: This code describes how to get data from database(mysql) as a resultset and convert the resultset into xml file using STAX writer......Also including multiple queries to get data from database and keep resultsets to convert multiple xml files according to the query

Answer (score -2):

Thanks all for replying , so far i have managed to get a solution based on using threads and use multiple selects instead of one single complex sql joins (i hate SQL complex ones) life should be simple :) so i didn't waste too much time writing them i am using new threads for each select statements.

any better solution in POJO probabaly using spring is also fine

Thanks
gauls

Comment: Multiple selects will likely slow you down.  Figure out the joins - that's why you have a database!